# Ui-grid not rendering cellTemplate properly in modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid inside of bootstrap modal. The data are filled correctly. The problem is occuring during the scrolling, all radio button appears unchecked and the data are still correct.

All the radio button are in a custom cell template, this kind of problem just happen in a modal. I made this example see in http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBr8ql5U9aEx6TqQyCNN?p=preview.

```
$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
.success(function(data) {
  var result = data;
  var len = result.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result[i].serie = 'A';
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
      result[i].serie = 'B';
    }
  }
  $rootScope.gridOptions.data = result;
});
```

The data are correct even if I change selecting another option, the data are update, but, if you scroll the ui-grid, the radio button are unchecked again.

Someone knows how solve this.

Thank you for help

Comment: It looks to me like the checking of A or B is correct once scrolling has occurred (based on the code snippet you have pasted above, which sets half of them to A and half to B), but sometimes ALL of the radio buttons are blank when the grid is first displayed. Is that the problem you wish to fix? Because your question seems to be saying that the problem is the checking of the radio buttons...

Comment: I change the question. The data are correct, the problem is occurring when the ui-grid is scrolling, the radio button are unchecked, but, the data still are the same.

Comment: OK, yes I can see that now and can confirm the bug.